# NSString to const char * convert with Greek characters

Tags: ios, nsstring, char, cons

I'm trying to convert an NSString which contains a greek word to a const char. I'm trying to convert the string with UTF-8 encoding which is for greek language and when i'm logging the char out, it has junk in it. Please a little help here..

```
//this is the greek word 
NSString *letter = textFieldLetter.text;

//NSString to const char conversion for the sql query
const char *cLetter = (const char *)[letter cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; 

//this contains junk!
NSLog(@"letter: %s",cLetter);
```

Comment: When using the character `π` in my string, I have no issues with that code.

Comment: when i'm inserting a greek string to a UItextField, i have NO problem. My problem is when i'm doing the conversion to const char, the final string has junk!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to use UTF8, instead use Unicode (**NSUnicodeStringEncoding**).

If you see the `NSStringEncoding` will see this options (have more):

```
enum {
NSWindowsCP1253StringEncoding = 13,    /* Greek */
NSUTF16StringEncoding = NSUnicodeStringEncoding,   

NSUTF16BigEndianStringEncoding = 0x90000100,          /* NSUTF16StringEncoding encoding with explicit endianness specified */
NSUTF16LittleEndianStringEncoding = 0x94000100,       /* NSUTF16StringEncoding encoding with explicit endianness specified */

NSUTF32StringEncoding = 0x8c000100,                   
NSUTF32BigEndianStringEncoding = 0x98000100,          /* NSUTF32StringEncoding encoding with explicit endianness specified */
NSUTF32LittleEndianStringEncoding = 0x9c000100        /* NSUTF32StringEncoding encoding with explicit endianness specified */
};
typedef NSUInteger NSStringEncoding;
```

You can see a specific Greek lenguage: `NSWindowsCP1253StringEncoding`

If is don't work, you can try to use other UTF16 or UTF32. But I think Unicode work for you.

-- edit

Take in mind that `NSLog(@"%s",string);` can not decode a unicode character. So, it will really show the mess.

To test if it work, do the conversion, and redo it. If is the same, so you don't lost data.

```
const char *cLetter = (const char *)[letter cStringUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding]; 
NSString *original = [NSString stringWithCString:cLetter encoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding];
```

Comment: I tested different encodings and NSWindowsCP1253Encoding worked for a test. But my problem is how can i convert an NSString to a const char for an sql statement. I have the following: NSString *original = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select * from vehicles where number='ΑΘΗΝΑ'; and const char *sqlStatement = (const char *)[original cStringUsingEncoding: NSWindowsCP1253StringEncoding]; Then i'm trying to (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) but no chance!

Comment: Ok i've solved it. It has to be const char *sqlStatement = [sqlState UTF8String]; before doing the sqlite3_prepare_v2. Thanks for your answer @Rodrigo.