# Convert string from special character

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsstringencoding

I am getting info using social framework and getting facebook info, when i get username in another language i.e Denis then it give me like **"\U00e6\U00f8\U00e5"**, how to convert this string to readable string i.e Denis?

Comment: If this is just `NSLog()` output, then leave it as-is. It's just escaped when printed - the string contains the correct Unicode characters.

Comment: @H2CO3 i have to use this username in creating profile,So i can not ignore this

Comment: So is it just `NSLog()` output, after all? Then you **can** ignore it.

Comment: I just check the response in NSLog(),And it's display what I said.What actual I want,is to use that response to show in My Profile SignUp View which i create.So how I can convert it.?

Comment: You don't need to convert it. Again, it's escaped when logged, but the string itself contains the appropriate characters.

Comment: @Harin - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10305488/nsstring-to-const-char-convert-with-greek-characters

Comment: @H2CO3 : i already try ,But it's Display in my View's textlable like : \U00e6\U00f8\U00e5 ..

Comment: @Harin: `"\U00e6\U00f8\U00e5"` is `"æøå"`, is this your real output? - You could get better help if you show your code: How do you get the string? How do you print the string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this usefull solution for my problem. [Check this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7861345/846191)

OR

```
int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSString *name2escaped = @"\U00e6\U00f8\U00e5";
        NSString *name2 = [NSString
            stringWithCString:[name2escaped cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
            encoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"name2 = %@", name2);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think these chracters are Unicode chracters, you can try something like this to convert them to UTF-8

http://effbot.org/zone/unicode-convert.htm

Answer (score 0):

Try with following code

Your string that you got,

`NSString *myStr = @".....`;

And use this code,

```
const wchar_t *myResulr = (const wchar_t*)[myStr cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF16StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"\n str2 = %S",myResulr);
```

This also may be [Helpful in your case.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFStringTokenizerRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFStringTokenizerCopyBestStringLanguage)

Comment: `NSUTF16StringEncoding` gives a sequence of `unichar`, which is 16-bit, but `wchar_t` is 32-bit, so this cannot work. - And note that the function `CFStringTokenizerCopyBestStringLanguage()` from your link guesses the *language*, not the *encoding*.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:"\u00e6\u00f8\u00e5"];
NSLog(@"%@", str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
NSString *str = @"\U00e6\U00f8\U00e5";

NSString *string = [NSString stringWithCString:[str UTF8String]  
                        encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"string: %@", string);
```

Comment: Why should it help to convert the NSString to UTF-8 and back to NSString? That gives exactly the original string.